# Join() Method query

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning how to use the join() in multithreading.I have a doubt in the following program.

When the main method first call the t1.join() does it put both the main thread as well as the t2 thread to wait or it is only the main thread that goes to wait?

```
public class App {

    private int count = 0;

    public void increment(){
        count++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app=new App();
        app.dowork();
    }

    public void dowork() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                    increment();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
                    increment();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        System.out.println("count is " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up a bit. [Jenkov's multithreading walkthrough](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html) explains multithreading in detail without overloading you with information. To answer; you cause the main thread to wait until completion of the first thread and then wait for the completion of the second thread. But if you look closely, Consider the following:

You have 3 threads, the main thread, thread 1 and thread 2. The main thread starts the other two threads and then waits on thread 1. However both thread 1 and thread 2 are allowed to continue and only the main thread will be waiting until thread 1 is complete. If thread 2 would still be alive after completion of thread 1, the main thread will be waiting for thread 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here only your main thread will be suspended until `t1` thread finishes. After that also main thread will wait until `t2` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

When you `t1.join()` the main thread blocks and waits for thread `t1` to finish. Thread `t2` is unaffected. Once `t1` completes the main thread will resume then execute `t2.join()` where it will wait for `t2` to finish.

Answer (score 0):

t1.join() causes the calling thread (presumably in this case main) to wait for t1.  Similarly for t2.join()